# Linux command line 'ls /path/*.*' yields "No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, command-line

I execute the command `sudo ls /path.../*.*` on a directory which requires root access. The command returns `No such file or directory`. However, running `sudo rm /path.../` gives me hundreds of files. Similarly I cannot do `sudo rm /path.../xyz*.*`, but I can do `sudo rm /path.../exactFileName.abc`.

How can I show/delete multiple files at once with the asterisk?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I show/delete multiple files at once with the asterisk [on a directory which requires root access]?

You can:

- execute a shell as root or user that has access to that directory

  - either interactively, `su -`, `sudo su -`, or `sudo sh`, or any other, and then type the commad
  - or non-interactively `sudo sh -c 'ls /path/*.*'`, or maybe `sudo sh -c 'ls "$1"/*.*' _ "$path"`
- or execute another command to get list of files and make that command run with sufficient permissions to access the path

  - `sudo find /path -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.*' -exec ls {} +`
  - `sudo find /path -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.*' -print0 | sudo xargs -0 ls`

Comment: `ls` will not have root permissions.

Comment: och right, so.. `-exec` it is.